# activate or deactivate Addons via command line or config file

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to activate or deactivate firefox addons via command line or config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `-safe-mode`, no: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/command_line_options.